# SQL Server - Remove duplicates with different ordering

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have a table containing pairs of items bought together and the # of times the pairing occurred.

```
item_1    item_2    count
  123       234        5
  345       567       22
  567       345       22
  890       345        6
```

Some of the pairings are dupes that differ just by order (ie rows 2&3).

Is there an easy way to de-dupe this table?

Answer (score 0):

You can classify a pair being the same with comparison similar to the least and greatest of the two. And select one of them.

```
select item_1,item_2,count 
from (select t.*
      ,row_number() over(partition by case when item_1<item_2 then item_1 else item_2 end,
                                      case when item_1>item_2 then item_1 else item_2 end 
                         order by item_1) as rnum
      from tbl t
     ) t
where rnum=1
```

Edit: Per Gordon's comment, if the duplicates have to eliminated only when the count is the same, use

```
select item_1,item_2,count 
from (select t.*
      ,row_number() over(partition by case when item_1<item_2 then item_1 else item_2 end,
                                      case when item_1>item_2 then item_1 else item_2 end,
                         count 
                         order by item_1) as rnum
      from tbl t
     ) t
where rnum=1
```

Comment: This doesn't account for the `count` being the same.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ..edited the answer to include `count` as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the "dups" can appear only once in either direction, then a convenient way is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.item_1 <= t.item_2
union all
select t.*
from t t
where t.item_1 > t.item2 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.item_1 = t.item_2 and t.item_2 = t.item_1 and t2.count = t.count
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (item_1  INT, item_2  INT , [count] INT)
INSERT INTO @T
VALUES
  (123       ,234,        5),
  (345       ,567,       22),
  (567       ,345,       22),
  (890       ,345,        6)

;WITH BASE AS
(
    SELECT RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY item_1),  * FROM @T
)
SELECT T1.item_1, T1.item_2, T1.count FROM BASE T1
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * 
                    FROM BASE T2 
                 WHERE T2.RN > T1.RN AND T1.item_1 = T2.item_2 AND T1.item_2 = T2.item_1) X
WHERE X.RN IS NULL
```

Result

```
item_1      item_2      count
----------- ----------- -----------
123         234         5
567         345         22
890         345         6
```